# access a property in UIView in Viewcontroller?

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have been given a project to edit. I think this is a simple question but want to explain it in detail.I usually set up iPhone projects with interface builder and then have a view controller h and m file.

However this has been set up in a different way I am new to, the view has been coded.

The h file is a simple viewcontroller class like this:

```
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController
 {
 }
 - (id)init;
 @end
```

And then the m file has this:

```
@interface MainView : UIView 
{
 NSUinterger firstinterger;
}

- (id)initWithImages:(NSArray *)inImages;

@end
```

And then it has the `@implementation MainView` just after that with lots more code.

Further down however is where I need to add my code just after

```
@end 

@implementation MainViewController
```

But I need to access the NSUinterger named first integer and I am unable to. I have tried a few ways of synthesizing etc. but I think I am doing it wrong. How I would get the value of it? I can access it in the code before the `@implementation MainViewController` but not after which is where I need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Synthesize the variable in `MainView`. Have an instance of the `MainView` in `MainViewController` and then you can access it by

```
MainView *mv = [[MainView alloc] init]; 
mv.firstInteger // gives you the variable.
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, what do you mean exactly by have a instance of mainview in mainviewcontroller? in the h or m file?

Comment: You need an object for that class. When you create using nibs u have an instance called view to reference the view. similarly u need to have such an instance to refer the Main view

Comment: Ok so i have this, and i can now compile without any errors, however when i compile the value and try and use that method the value is always 0. It is not normally 0 as i have used a NSLOG to test it, just when i use that method it is 0?

Comment: well, not sure either on this one, but im sure it was easier to access a NSNumber than a NSUinteger? give that a try instead - unsure of the reasons behind it

Answer (score 0):

`NSUinterger firstinterger` in your code shows no ';' at the end of that line, do you get compilation errors or is it just a typo in your question?

Comment: Thats just a typo sorry, ill fix it

Comment: food for though right, if you wish to access variables / objects across many classes - consider a singleton class. what you are trying to do simply will cause issues as its not thread safe (am i right any one??) i tried this when I began coding and had to find a solution to store a few variables that any class / object could access, singleton is your life saver.

Comment: Thanks, I know i never do it this way, however i have to get the project the exact same but just add some code in.